# getting multiple file values in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<input type="file" name="prod_detail_image[]" id="prod_detail_image" 
       value=""  multiple="multiple" onblur="validatebutton();" />
```

I can choose multiple files in the file input. In onblur event I need to get the file values which was selected. I am getting only one value. I need to get the array values of images.

Comment: where's your code? where's the error? javascript, php, html?

Comment: I have used the above html code. And I need to get the image array value in javascript. But there I am getting only one image value instead of 3 or 4 values..

Comment: first of all remove the value, secondly ignore the spaces in your name, fill it up with underscores..thirdly ignore name and id to be same..and last but not the lease edit your question, give your javascript/php whatever you think it fails and than wait for an answer

Comment: var files = document.forms['addproduct']["prod_detail_image[]"];
alert(files.length);

Comment: This is my javascript code for getting the image array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other similar questions on SO.  Here is a simple way to get all the filenames

```
var inp = document.getElementById('prod_detail_image');
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
    var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
    alert("here is a file name: " + name);
}
```

However this will only work in browsers that support HTML5

Answer (score 0):

```
var inp = document.getElementById('prod_detail_image');
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; i++) {
var name = inp.files[i].name;
alert("here is a file name: " + name);
}
```

check this.It will work.